# How is a StringBuilder implemented to avoid the immutable string allocation problem?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

How is a `StringBuilder` implemented to avoid the immutable string allocation problem?

```
StringBuilder aliasA = new StringBuilder("a");
StringBuilder dot = new StringBuilder(".");
Clausula clause1 = new Clausula(aliasA.append(dot).append("id").toString());
Clausula clause2 = new Clausula(aliasA.append(dot).append("name").toString());
```

Comment: Maybe you can check the code of  `StringBuilder`, it's open source.

Comment: Because appending to a `StringBuilder` doesn't create a new object.

Comment: You can have a read on the following. I will shed some light. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html

Comment: `StringBuilder` is basically the same as a `String`, in the sense that both are principally wrappers around a `char[]`. The only (relevant) difference is that `StringBuilder` provides API methods to change that array, whilst `String` does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using a `char` array. You can see this in the JDK source. In JDK 1.8 (the one I have the source for handy), `StringBuilder` is built on top of `AbstractStringBuilder` which uses this to hold the data:

```
char[] value;
int    count;
```

([Karol Dowbecki says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023886/157247) that JDK 9 "sometimes" uses `byte` instead of `char`; I have no reason to doubt him. :-) )

`count` tells the class how much of `value` is actual data vs. just available space in the array. It starts out with a `char[16]` (unless you tell it in advance what capacity you may require) and reallocates and copies as needed.

It only creates a string when you call `toString`, using the [`String(char[],int,int)` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D,int,int)) (or presumably one accepting `byte[]` sometimes JDK9) to make a copy of the portion of the array's contents that are actually used:

```
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Behind the scene it uses a `char[]` (or `byte[]` in JDK 9 or newer) to store the characters. New String object is created only after calling `StringBuilder.toString()`.